# Uncheck box is other is selected with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a several checkboxes like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-default">
                <input type="checkbox" name="RAT_RoomList[]" value="10">
                <label for="custome-checkbox1"># 11</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-default">
                <input type="checkbox" name="RAT_RoomList[]" value="11">
                <label for="custome-checkbox2"># 12</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-default">
                <input type="checkbox" name="RAT_RoomList[]" value="12">
                <label for="custome-checkbox3"># 13</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-default">
                <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">
                <label for="custome-checkbox">Select all</label>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

How can unselect all other when the `Select all` is checked and how can I unselect `Select All` when one of the other checkboxes is checked?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you *un*select all others when "Select All" is checked? Anyway, have you tried adding `click` or `change` handlers to the checkboxes and testing the current `checked` status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using not Selector with class you can achieve this.

```js
$('.selectAll').click(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
    $(".col-sm-12").find('input[type=checkbox]').not('.selectAll').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});
$('input[type=checkbox]').not('.selectAll').click(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
    $('.selectAll').prop("checked", false)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-default">
      <input type="checkbox" name="RAT_RoomList[]" value="10">
      <label for="custome-checkbox1"># 11</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-default">
      <input type="checkbox" name="RAT_RoomList[]" value="11">
      <label for="custome-checkbox2"># 12</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-default">
      <input type="checkbox" name="RAT_RoomList[]" value="12">
      <label for="custome-checkbox3"># 13</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-default">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">
      <label for="custome-checkbox">Select all</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if it address your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lt2k8wxL/

```
$('.selectAll').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('input[name="RAT_RoomList[]"]').prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$('input[name="RAT_RoomList[]"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.selectAll').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.